# Does using a draconic sorcerer's Draconic Presence break concentration for a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spellcasting

The feature [Draconic Presence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) states

> As an action, you can spend 5 sorcery points to draw on this power and exude an aura of awe or fear (your choice) to a distance of 60 feet. For 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (as if you were casting a concentration spell), each hostile creature that starts its turn in this aura must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be charmed (if you chose awe) or frightened (if you chose fear) until the aura ends.

Which would obviously mean that casting a spell after using Draconic Presence would break concentration.

However, the rules for spell concentration states

> **Casting another spell that requires concentration.** You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

But if you were to cast a concentration spell and use Draconic Presence, would the Spell effect end?

Draconic Presence isn't a spell and it isn't even magical. It states the condition to losing Draconic Presence's concentration but it doesn't change that only concentration spells break a creature's concentration on another spell (that isn't damage).

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Draconic presence says:

> *as if you were casting a concentration spell*,

which means draconic presence is treated *as if you were casting a concentration spell*. Therefore, all rules that apply to concentration spells apply to draconic presence. So you would drop concentration on a concentration spell if you used draconic presence.

To put it another way, it is not a spell, it isn’t even magical, but its description explicitly states you are to treat it *as if you were casting a concentration spell*.

Additionally, we have this rule clarified in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*:

> As soon as you start casting a spell or using a special ability that requires concentration, your concentration on another effect ends instantly.

Comment: But that should only be the case where you're resolving when it's ending. I'm asking about the fact that it doesn't specify whether it would end a spell.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: Before the parenthetical phrase, it says "until you lose concentration." It feels like it's implying that the parenthetical phrase is in reference to that specific situation.

Comment: Yeah, I understand where you’re coming from. I’m arguing that the parenthetical phrase means we’re treating the ability *as if it were a concentration spell*. It’s my perspective. Great question.